# Why ART need Relocate?

Tags: android, dalvik

ART relocate the boot.art & boot.oat  under `/system/framework/arm/` to `/data/dalvik-cache/arm/` by default.

Why the art  likes to use the cached one rather than the system one?

Why not just use the boot image under `/system`?

Comment: While this is a good question, it's really not about programming. Possibly more suited to android.stackexchange.com?

Answer (score 0):

I guess, in Android L & M, the boot.art and boot.oat use the absolute address to load boot.art & boot.oat. But, sometime, ART can't load them at special base address, so, ART load them by another base address. Therefore ART must relocate the  address of classes in boot.art.

See the code: ./runtime/gc/space/image_space.cc RelocateImage

```
  std::string base_offset_arg("--base-offset-delta=");
  StringAppendF(&base_offset_arg, "%d", hooseRelocationOffsetDelta(ART_BASE_ADDRESS_MIN_DELTA,                            ART_BASE_ADDRESS_MAX_DELTA));
```

the base-offset-delta is used to calculate the new address of classes in boot.art.